# Creating an "overlay" Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have a few activities, and when I start them, the activity that started them is stopped. However, I don't want it to be stopped, only paused. How can I achieve this?

For example, Google Play Games has these "inbox" and "create match" activities that do NOT stop the activity that launched them, so I guess they somehow "overlay" the activity. How do they work?

Answer (score 1):

An activity is at the very least paused when another activity starts.

See [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

If you want to overlay your activity then a possible solution would be to use a [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a new activity, use one one activity and use 2 fragments, one with the content of each of you original activities. You can inflate them as needed.